# How to properly hide process?

Tags: vb.net, process

How to properly hide process?

I m using these five lines of code, for another process, but somehow it is still not hidden, or to say it is still visible on screen. Do you know what line of code am i missing?

What I have tried:

```
  Dim myprocess As Process = New Process()
  myprocess.StartInfo.FileName = "SW.exe"
  myprocess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
  myprocess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
  myprocess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
  myprocess.Start()
  myprocess.WaitForExit()
```

Comment: Some processes disagree when you try to hide their Window. -- Some processes are just a stub: these run another process and quit right after. For example, Control Panel applets; they're run by `rundll32.exe` with arguments like `shell32.dll, Control_RunDLL ...`. If this is the case, you can use `myprocess.WaitForInputIdle` and (try to) use [ShowWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow) to modify the Window *visibility*. You have to find it, though. `FindWindowEx` may be enough, but there's the chance you need `EnumThreadWindows`.

Comment: `UseShellExecute = False`

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the `CreateNoWindow` property has this to say:

> If the UseShellExecute property is true or the UserName and Password
>   properties are not null, the CreateNoWindow property value is ignored
>   and a new window is created.

The answer to your question is exactly where you should have expected it to be. ALWAYS read the documentation.